# How to extract all footnotes from a MS Word file?

Tags: ms-word, text-extraction, footnotes

Is there a generic (Macro, XML Parser, ...) way to extract all footnotes in a MS Word file and also keep the corresponding number from the original text?

Answer (score 1):

You might use Elod Pal Czirmaz's [macro](http://www.epcsirmaz.co.uk/?q=word) as a starting point.  I suspect that footnotes don't carry their numbers with them.  When the document is rendered, the numbers are just assigned in order.